# Inside listView button onclick not getting access data to display

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

Below is my listview customAdapter class getView method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    YourWrapper wrapper = null;
    HashMap<String, Object> cTa= new HashMap<String, Object>();
    cTa= d.getPosition(position)
    if (row == null)
    {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
        wrapper = new YourWrapper (row);
        row.setTag(wrapper);
    }
    else
        wrapper = (YourWrapper) row.getTag();

    wrapper.getButton().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //operation-1 
        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

I have to disply message on **operation-1** area getting data from **cTa**. Only final variables are allowed on operation-1 region. But cTa can not be final by definition. So please help me how to get the access cTa here. or any other alternative's. Thanks!

Comment: can;t you declare globally?

Comment: no, then cTa cannot be assigned inside getView().

Comment: If possible, you could implement the onclicklisstener on the class. Then you could access the variables. Instead of adding an anonymous inneclass

Comment: @RobinHood, Thank you sir, I was wrong in declaring cTa globally. Really a silly mistake. previously tried by declaring the cTa as final in globally, Now just removing the final make it so. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    YourWrapper wrapper = null;

    if (row == null)
    {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
        wrapper = new YourWrapper (row);
        row.setTag(wrapper);
    }
    else
        wrapper = (YourWrapper) row.getTag();

    wrapper.getButton().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
             HashMap<String, Object> cTa= new HashMap<String, Object>(d.getPosition(position));
              // Your operation
        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    YourWrapper wrapper = null;
    HashMap<String, Object> cTa= new HashMap<String, Object>();
    cTa= d.getPosition(position)
    if (row == null)
    {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
        wrapper = new YourWrapper (row);
        row.setTag(wrapper);
    }
    else
        wrapper = (YourWrapper) row.getTag();
    wrapper.getButton.setTag(cTa);
    wrapper.getButton().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            HashMap<String, Object> cTa = (HashMap)v.getTag(); 
        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly working for me

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView listview;
List<Map<String,Object>> data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    prepareData(); 

    listview =new ListView(this);
    MySimpleAdapter adapter=new MySimpleAdapter(this,data,R.layout.activity_item,new String[]      {"uu"},new int[]{R.id.showTv});
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);                            
    setContentView(listview);

}


private void prepareData(){
       data=new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
       Map<String,Object> item;
       item=new HashMap<String,Object>();
       item.put("din", "hello");
       data.add(item);
       item=new HashMap<String,Object>();
       item.put("bin", "world");
       data.add(item);
       item=new HashMap<String,Object>();
       item.put("tin", "rock");
       data.add(item);
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
     }
 }
```

Adapter Class

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

private final Context context;
private List<Map<String, Object>> data;
private int resource;
private String[] from;
private int[] to;

public MySimpleAdapter(Context context,
        List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from,int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
       this.context=context;
       this.data=(List<Map<String, Object>>) data;
       this.resource=resource;
       this.from=from;
       this.to=to;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(resource, null, true);
    Map<String,Object> medMap = data.get(position);
    final TextView[] showTv = new TextView[from.length];

    Button btn1 = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.gointoBt);

    Button.OnClickListener mOkOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener()
      {
         public void onClick(View v) {

             Toast.makeText(context, "my pos " + "button1 "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


         }
     };
     btn1.setOnClickListener(mOkOnClickListener);


     Button btn2=(Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.chooseBt);
     Button.OnClickListener mOkOnClickListener2 = new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "my pos " + "button2 "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
     btn2.setOnClickListener(mOkOnClickListener2);     
     return rowView; 

}


 }
```

Have fun..